# Displaying issues with GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm programming a simple calculator in Java using Swing and i'm having trouble with the GridBagLayout.

Here's how i have sliced my components:

[image: my window]

[image]

So as you can see, the cos sin tan % log sqrt sqr and pi buttons are not supposed to be far away from the other ones.

Also, this is what happens when i reduced the size of the window when the program is launched :

[image]

The buttons are displayed the way i want them to be displayed but the JTable is displayed weirdly.

Here's some informations about the mainwindow:

preferred size : 600*600
Jtable : no size informations setted

and every component has his weight attribute setted to 0 in the GridBagConstraints object (i think it could come from this

EDIT: some code! this is the enum that i use to initialize my buttons, so you can see the GridBagConstraints.

```
//new GridBagConstraints(int gridx, int gridy, int gridwidth, int gridheight, double weightx, double weighty, 
//int anchor, int fill, Insets insets, int ipadx, int ipady);
ZERO("0", 96, new GridBagConstraints(5,5,1,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0)), //
        ONE("1", 97, new GridBagConstraints(4,4,1,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0)), //
        TWO("2", 98, new GridBagConstraints(5,4,1,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0)), //
        THREE("3", 99, new GridBagConstraints(6,4,1,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0)), //
        FOUR("4", 100, new GridBagConstraints(4,3,1,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0)), //
        FIVE("5", 101, new GridBagConstraints(5,3,1,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0)), //
        SIX("6", 102, new GridBagConstraints(6,3,1,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0)), //
        SEVEN("7", 103, new GridBagConstraints(4,2,1,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0)), //
        EIGHT("8", 104, new GridBagConstraints(5,2,1,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0)), //
        NINE("9", 105, new GridBagConstraints(6,2,1,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0)), //
        DOT(".", 110, new GridBagConstraints(6,5,1,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0)), //
        PLUS("+", 107, new GridBagConstraints(7,2,1,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0)), //
        MINUS("-", 109, new GridBagConstraints(7,3,1,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0)), //
        DIVIDE("/", 111, new GridBagConstraints(7,5,1,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0)), //
        MULTIPLY("*", 106, new GridBagConstraints(7,4,1,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0)), //
        MODULO("%", 0, new GridBagConstraints(7,6,1,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0)), //
        EQUAL("=", 10, new GridBagConstraints(4,5,1,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0)), //
        CLEAR("C", 67, new GridBagConstraints(7,1,1,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0)), //
        BACKSPACE("Bck", 8, new GridBagConstraints(7,0,1,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0)), //
        CLEARHISTORY("Clear history", 72, new GridBagConstraints(0,7,4,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0)), //
        COSINUS("cos", 72, new GridBagConstraints(4,6,1,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0)), //
        SINUS("sin", 72, new GridBagConstraints(5,6,1,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0)), //
        TANGENT("tan", 72, new GridBagConstraints(6,6,1,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0)), //
        SQUAREROOT("sqrt", 72, new GridBagConstraints(5,7,1,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0)), //
        SQUARE("sqr", 72, new GridBagConstraints(6,7,1,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0)), //
        LOGARITHM("log", 72, new GridBagConstraints(4,7,1,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0)), //
        PLUSMINUS("±", 72, new GridBagConstraints(7,7,1,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0));
```

and this is the code where i initialize the View:

```
        CALCULATIONSHISTORYLABEL(new GridBagConstraints(0,0,4,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0)),
        CALCULATIONSHISTORYTABLE(new GridBagConstraints(0,1,4,6,0,0,GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0)),
        CURRENTCALCULATIONLABEL(new GridBagConstraints(4,0,3,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.LINE_END,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0)),
        CURRENTRESULTLABEL(new GridBagConstraints(4,1,3,1,0,0,GridBagConstraints.LINE_END,
                GridBagConstraints.NONE,new Insets(5,5,5,5),0,0));

/*...*/

    public View() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("simpleCount");
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        calculationsHistoryView = new JTable();

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        add(new JLabel("Calculations History"), ComponentPlacement.CALCULATIONSHISTORYLABEL.gbc);
        add(new JScrollPane(calculationsHistoryView), ComponentPlacement.CALCULATIONSHISTORYTABLE.gbc);

        add(currentCalculationView, ComponentPlacement.CURRENTCALCULATIONLABEL.gbc);
        add(currentResultView, ComponentPlacement.CURRENTRESULTLABEL.gbc);
        for (int i = 0; i < Button.values().length; i++) {
            add(buttonsView.getButtons()[i], Button.values()[i].gbc);
        }
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        requestFocus();
    }
```

Could anyone help me ?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: did you set the height and width of all the components to zero? assuming you are trying to evenly space everything out.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a single layout manager for the entire frame.

The default layout manager is a BorderLayout for the frame and I would stick with this.

Then you can create a "buttons panel" with your GridBagLayout and add the panel using:

```
frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
```

Then you can create another "left panel" which again might use a BorderLayout. Then you could

1. add the top label to BorderLayout.PAGE_START
2. add the table to BorderLayout.CENTER
3. add the bottom label to BorderLayout.PAGE_END

and finally add the left panel to the frame:

```
frame.add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Now all the extra space in the frame will go to the table.

Answer (score -1):

I think there could be two issues:

1. Try to set stretch width and height of table scroll from 0.1 to 1.0 (more than zero) and set stretch strategy to `GridBagLayout.BOTH`
2. Set `minPrefferedHeight()` and `minPrefferedWidth()` of `JScrollPane` which is table container.

Comment: See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)  The rest remaining seems really better suited to a comment.

Comment: The choice is yours. Some swing components have 'strange' behavior and   for these situations java api provides many methods, which we have to use not to hate them ;)

Comment: You missed the major point of that thread.  The answers mention that in the rare case you need to change those values, it is typically a better design to **`@Override`** the relevant methods according to the need.  Calling `set..Size` methods, we are usually just making a random guess as to the numbers required.